# EXCEL - How can I copy in a cell all words starting with specific strings?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet full of words and sentences (in certain cells we can have several words).
I need to copy in a cell all words starting for example with XXX.

Do you have a VBA Script to do this quickly ?

Thank you.

Comment: We don't provide code. Can you show us how you're trying to implement your code? Also you can read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following UDF:

```
Public Function XXX(v As String) As String
    ary = Split(v, " ")
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        If Left(ary(i), 3) <> "XXX" Then ary(i) = " "
    Next i
    XXX = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(ary, " "))
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

This assumes that the words in a cell are separated by a single space.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InStr() function, sheck out [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php) for more information; this is a good start to point you in the right direction

**Example**

```
If (InStr(1, "FIND", "FIND WORK")) Then
    Msgbox "Found the work: 'FIND', within the string 'FIND WORD'", , ""
Else
    MsgBox "Word was not found", , ""
End If
```